# Matching constructor to counterpart in generic type definition

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have been thinking about this problem for a while and it feels like there must be a simple solution that I'm missing.

Let's say I have the following class:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
   public Foo(T value)
   {
   }

   public Foo(int value)
   {   
   }
}
```

If I get all constructors on the type `Foo<System.Int32>` I will get back two constructors, both with a single parameter of type `System.Int32` which cannot be differentiated.

If I get all constructors from the generic type definition of `Foo<System.Int32>` (`Foo<T>`) I will get back two constructors. One which accepts a generic parameter `T` and one that accepts a parameter of type `System.Int32`

```
// Will return two constructors with signatures that look identical.    
var type = typeof(Foo<int>);    
var ctors1 = type.GetConstructors();

// Will return two constructors as well. Parameters can be differentiated.
var genericTypeDefinition = typeof(Foo<int>).GetGenericTypeDefinition();
var ctors2 = genericTypeDefinition.GetConstructors();
```

Is there a way to match a constructor to its counterpart in its generic type definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Comparing the `ctors` in both cases you can compare their MetadataToken.
Example:

```
foreach (var item in ctors1)
{
    var ctorMatch = ctors2.SingleOrDefault(c => c.MetadataToken == item.MetadataToken);
}
```

Comment: Wow. Much simpler than I thought it would be. Thank you very much!